# Open program.exe without a command line window

Tags: c, windows, cmd, exe

I've made an program.exe, which gives no output by itself when you start it, it just starts a clean command line window.

The goal is to start it and there should be no command line windows, it should just run in the background.
I've tried it in the command line with "start /B program.exe", that works good.
But I dont want to type that in every time, and I dont want to create a batch file for that, because there should be just one exe file which I tranfser to any pc.
I Hope the question is clear.
Is there any possibility to do it like that?

Comment: It's a bit confusing description... "cmd /c start /b executable.exe". Where is the problem? but what is the reason?

Comment: i want to start an exe file in cmd with "start /B *.exe"
but i dont want to type that in, i just want to click on a file and it starts.
A solution would be to write a *.cmd file with "start /B *.exe" , but there should be just one file.

Comment: `editbin /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS the_exe_file.exe`  And then there will not be a console window opened.

Comment: @BenVoigt Where have to be that code?

Comment: @jonadev: That's not code, that's a tool (part of the Windows SDK) that modifies a flag in your .exe file to tell Windows not to create a console window for it.

Comment: If you are compiling with GCC, you can add the `-mwindows` flag.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Thats the solution I've searched for, thank you very much!

Comment: If you clean up your question to explain what you were trying to do in a way that would be useful to future searches, I will vote to reopen.

Comment: @DourHighArch I'm sorry, I dont know how to describe it.
I hope it is now understandable.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: after seeing the edits and comments on the question, it's clear that this isn't the right course of action. As noted in the comments, the right thing is to just make an .exe that doesn't connect to a console, instead of faking it as I showed here.

What about having your program call itself with the `start /b` functionality?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("in first process\n");
        system("start /b test.exe x");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("in second process\n");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to get no output from the system function?

Comment: You can redirect the output wherever you like, including changing it to `system("start /b test.exe x>nul");`.